# The viewpager in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want do some slides in my app, in the activity, the following code works fine, but in the fragment, the app crash and say something like "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference", how can I fix this?

The code in an activity:

```
private ViewPager frViewPager;
private int[] frImgIds = new int[]{R.drawable.pic_1,R.drawable.pic_2,R.drawable.pic_3};
private List<ImageView> mImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

frViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.landing_page);
frViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(LandingPageActivity.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(frImgIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        container.addView(imageView);
        mImages.add(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
    /* Other override code……*/
})
```

The code in a fragment:

```
private ViewPager frViewPager;
private int[] frImgIds = new int[]{R.drawable.pic_1,R.drawable.pic_2,R.drawable.pic_3};
private List<ImageView> mImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

frViewPager = (ViewPager) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recommend);
frViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setImageResource(frImgIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        container.addView(imageView);
        mImages.add(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
    /* Other override code……*/
})
```

Update:

```
04-16 02:04:33.951    1996-1996/com.demo.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.demo.example, PID: 1996
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.example/com.demo.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.demo.android.fragment.IndexFragment.onCreateView(IndexFragment.java:32)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Can you provide a full stacktrace of the error..

Comment: From the stacktrace, it clearly states that the error is occurring in the fragment. Assuming that the code for the fragment is extracted from it's onCreateView menthod, can you verify if the `frViewPager` is not null. Because setting an adapter to a `null` viewpager can cause this error.

Comment: i think `frViewPager` in `frViewPager = (ViewPager) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recommend);` is null i.e. please cross check that this `ViewPager` exists in same fragment?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) It should be 'frViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.recommend);'

Comment: @user2655973  if you have solved the issue, put it as the answer and accept it your own. It will save others time.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `frViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.recommend);`